# android BroadcastReceiver: onReceive() method of Receiver is not getting called

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I have registered a receiver in manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.receiverdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.receiverdemo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="Receiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.receiverdemo.RECEIVER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and I am sending broadcast from adb shell as

`adb shell am broadcast -a com.example.receiverdemo.RECEIVER`

the above command should get executed properly and the `onReceive()` method of `Receiver` should get called after that.

This is the expected behavior.

I can see this behavior on `emulator` and `galaxy nexus` both running android 4.2 but this is not working as expected on my `HTC one X` and `HTC-desire-x` both running android 4.1.1, the `onReceive()` method is not getting called, even though `am broadcast` command is getting executed properly.

I can see the output as

```
shell@android:/ $ am broadcast -a com.example.receiverdemo.RECEIVER
am broadcast -a com.example.receiverdemo.RECEIVER
Broadcasting: Intent { act=com.example.receiverdemo.RECEIVER }
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

`Receiver` class is as follows,

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String ACTION_RECEIVER = "com.example.receiverdemo.RECEIVER";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Log.i("DEMO", "Working");
    }
}
```

I am not getting what is going wrong here. Is it something related with API versions or ROMs or some developer settings or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rooted my device and from adb shell with root privileges executed that command, and its working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try to comment `android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"` for this receiver.